# In which case we use Static Router or BrowserRouter or HashRouter and why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem.I have read many blogs but can't able to find why and in which specific case we use these Router type?

Comment: What of the documentation for [hashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter), [browserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) or [memoryRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter) don't you understand?

Comment: @HMR No I Can't able to understand from there because they have mentioned in brief. Please help me on this.

Comment: What of the explanation there do you not understand? What information is missing and what you are having trouble with?

Comment: @poke as mentioned in the docs HashRouter - uses the hash portion of the URL and what is hash portion of URL are they talking about Fragment or anything else ? and similarly for Browser Router -  that uses the HTML5 history API and they have also not mentioned why and when we use these routers and for what use-cases they are suitable for ? - Please help me in detail

Comment: The hash router even mentions `window.location.hash` which should give you something you can google to see that it is the fragment of the URL. The docs say that the memory router is _“useful in tests and non-browser environments”_ and the hash router says _“As this technique is only intended to support legacy browsers, we encourage you to configure your server to work with BrowserHistory instead”_. To me that sounds like a clear recommendation for the BrowserRouter by default unless you are in one of the other explained cases.

Comment: To understand why static router is needed, please refer to this article --> https://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2020/03/02/static-router-static-assets-serving-a-server-side-rendered-site

Answer (score -1):

try looking at - [cick](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

**BrowserRouter** for the browser and static requests for the server (SSR), and **HashRouter** must be used for a static site (adds **#**)

Comment: As, I have mentioned above this site contain very less information about the router type. Please help me on -  why and when we use these routers and for what use-cases they are suitable for ?

Comment: so I tell you. BrowserRouter is used for browsers and SSRs, and HashRouter is used only for static sites.

Comment: Why HashRouter shouldn’t be used for non-static sites? Btw, the link is broken.